# Is there any online text editor for HTML, CSS with saving and syntax highlighting facility?

Tags: css, xhtml

I want to make css file from accessible from everywhere (home, office etc) and ready to edit.
and save.

I will do hand coding ,just want syntax highlighting and saving on net facility.

I tried google docs (it's good because i can save online and it has revision history feature too which is useful)  but it doesn't have syntax highlighting and also tried http://www.amyeditor.com/ it's same as i want but it save file on our local pc.

and i usually use jsbin.com but i heard it will delete the code if nothing will happen to code in 3 month.

**Update:**

In nutshell I'm looking for online editor like Dreamweaver source view. with code hosting too.

**Update 2**

i found it useful but , no facility for saving.

http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/csstest.html

Answer (score 0):

https://bespin.mozilla.com/

Bespin is a mozilla project with a lot of potential. I couldn't recommend it more highly.

Comment: I think it's needs learning curve to use. but it's a mozilla product so we can rely on this. other small services can gone without notice. can u give some more guidance how we can use this for css development if u r experienced with it

Answer (score 0):

See following
http://snipplr.com
http://gist.github.com/

See [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/78756/what-do-you-use-to-keep-notes-as-a-developer-closed) if you could get any solution.

If you don't like then **use a blog** with **[syntaxhighlighter](http://alexgorbatchev.com/wiki/SyntaxHighlighter).**

Comment: i need like this http://marijn.haverbeke.nl/codemirror/csstest.html with saving facility. ur suggested solutions are different.

Answer (score 0):

[Dabblet](http://dabblet.com/) is pretty impressive !

Saves to github gists. For more info look at the [help/about page](http://dabblet.com/help/)

Answer (score -3):

You could just use wordpad witch comes with windows, and then you could upload it to a server such as [Dropbox](http://www.dropbox.com/). Simples.(Make sure you put .css at the end of the filename).

Comment: Original author is looking specifically for an online solution with syntax highlighting.

Comment: OK Sorry. I will try not to do that next time in an answer