# Javascript - Online CSS Editor

Tags: javascript

I'm searching for an online JavaScript CSS editor like this:

[image]

Did somebody know of one?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I found [this](http://cssmate.com/csseditor.html) for online CSS editor.
There are some others [here](http://resources.savedelete.com/top-10-free-online-css-editors-for-web-designers.html).

I have also found similar questions at Stackoverflow [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2367099/best-online-code-editor-with-a-textarea) and [here](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2063154/is-there-any-online-text-editor-for-html-css-with-saving-and-syntax-highlighting).

For downloadable javascript-based CSS editor I found [this](http://sourceforge.net/projects/htmlcsseditor/).

[Firebug Lite](http://getfirebug.com/firebuglite) (source-code [here](https://getfirebug.com/releases/lite/latest/firebug-lite.tar.tgz)) is javascript-based and is compatible with lots of browsers.

Comment: I use codemirror at the moment. But that is not what i want. The only editor is this -> http://cssmate.de/csseditor.html .. But there is no download link :/

Comment: You mean you want to embed the editor in your page? It is not clear from your question (at least for me).

Comment: Right! I search a script wich i can embed in my page. Sorry, my english is not so good. Its hard for me to explain it.